# What does the linkSite option do with Google Custom Search API?

Tags: google-custom-search

[Google Custom Search API docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) says "Specifies that all search results should contain a link to a particular URL"

Does the general Google Search have this as a advanced option, if so what is the option? I am getting results that are just weird, possibly I don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

General Google Search has a "link:" option that is kind of same as the CSE "linkSite".

But with CSE, it seems that the linkSite-option is not restricted to the sites that are listed at CSE configuration, AKA. other sites may appear in the results, sites that are not listed in CSE configuration